# ListView revert changes when SelectedItem changed

Tags: wpf, listview

I Have ListView for list of objects and propertyGrid for changes properties of object. All working fine, values changing, saving to database working too. BUT when i selected other item in ListView(i try other components they do this too) previous edited item revert all changes back. I dont know why he do that but i tried to search solution and nothing found. Btw: In ObservableCollection which binding to ListView, all data revert too.

Comment: if you're binding your object to PropertyGrid, can you try using TwoWay binding mode?

Comment: yes. this is by default

Comment: try setting it explicitly. or post your codes